# How do I remove these whitespaces of my site?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I am making a shop for my server, the shop lets me edit only the css, which I am doing, but in the shop there is a giant white space to the right, top and bottom of the screen.

I tried looking for css solutions, non of them worked.

How do I fix this?

**WEBSITE: http://purgepvp-mc.tebex.io/?theme=174117**

**CSS*:*

```
        @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato;
    @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Futura);

    .header {

        background-size: cover;
        padding: 20px;
        margin: 0;
        background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/eFt7yL2.jpg");        

    }

    .progress-bar {

      background-color: #592e89  

    }

    body > .container {
        width: 100% !important;
        padding: 0 !important;
        background: #757575;
    }


    .panel-heading {

        border-radius: 0px !important;
        border: 0px !important;
        height: 40px !important;
        background-color: #592e89 !important;
        color: #FFF !important;
        border-radius: 0px !important;


    }

    .logo {





    }

    .panel {

        border: none !important;
        border-radius: 0px !important;


    }

    .panel-body {


        color: #FFF !important;
        border-radius: 0px !important;
        background-color: #3a3a3a;

    }


    .content {


        border: none !important;


    }

    .navbar {

        border-radius: 1px;
        color: white;
        background-color: #592e89;
        border: none !important;

    }


    .donation-goal {

        font-weight: bold;

    }

    .nav {
        margin: 0 auto;
        text-align: center;
        display: block;
        width: max-content;
        float: initial;'
        font-weight: bold;'

    }

    .nav a, .nav li {
        color: #FFF !important;
        transition: all 0.2s linear;
        text-decoration: none !important;
        font-weight: bold;
    }



    .nav li:hover, .nav li:hover a {
        background-color: #3a3a3a;
        color: #FFF !important;
        text-decoration: none !important;
        border-radius: 20px;
        font-weight: bold;

    }






    @-webkit-keyframes pulse {
      0% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
      }
      50% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
      }
      100% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
      }
    }

    @keyframes pulse {
      0% {
        transform: scale(1);
      }
      50% {
        transform: scale(1.1);
      }
      100% {
        transform: scale(1);
      }
    }




    .logo img {
        content: url('https://i.imgur.com/S7Lfi8X.jpg');
        height: initial !important;
        width: 600px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        display: block;
    }

    .logo {
        width: 100% !important;
      animation: pulse 3s infinite;
      margin: 0 auto;
      display: table;
      margin-top: 50px;
      animation-direction: alternate;
      -webkit-animation-name: pulse;
      animation-name: pulse;
    }



    .footer {

        border-top: 5px solid #592e89;
        background-color: #3a3a3a;
        padding-bottom: 30px;
        font-weight: bold;

    }
```

Comment: If you would, please post all the code relevant to the question *in the question itself* - don't hide it behind a link. You shouldn't tell potential helpers who would otherwise love to help that they have to navigate offsite just to have an idea of what you're working with. If the link breaks, the question could be rendered useless to future readers. Please edit your code into the question in a [MCVE], or the question might get closed, thanks.

Comment: it's your `pulse animation` together with your `float: left` ... remove float left from `.header .logo` and any media queries where you override it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logo caused this. 
Add this css

```
body .container {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.container .body {
  margin-right:0px;
  margin-left:0px;
}

body {
  margin-top: 0px !important; /*in your syle.min.css, it makes the margin-top:20px*/
}
```

Comment: How about the grey area at the bottom of the site?

Comment: if you mean the footer, you can just remove the html code or use this css.
`.footer {
  display: none;
}`

Answer (score 0):

There is a margin available by default, 
for example

```
<head>
   title scripts etc.
</head>
<body>
    <header class="...">your html</header>
    <div class="..."></div>
</body>
```

Either give an id or class to the body and make margin = 0 in the body class or hard code

```
<body style="margin:0;">
    <header class="...">your html</header>
    <div class="..."></div>
</body>
```

This will prevent the white space.